# Android alertdialog custom layout button onClickListener crashes

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I have made a layout for my alertdialog and there I have a exit button that calls `dialog.dismiss()` and a few more that save data to preferences. I have set onClickListeners to all and my dialog does not have any button such as positive or negative, only the ones in the layout.

However the app crashes when calling the dialog.

> ```
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at com.xcommerce.androidstore.HomeScreen$21.onClick(HomeScreen.java:1183)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
> 08-20 07:58:01.291: E/AndroidRuntime(3297):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

```
TextView sort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sorteaza);
        final Dialog sortDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
        sort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater inflater = HomeScreen.this.getLayoutInflater();
                View sortView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_layout, null);
                sortDialog.setContentView(sortView);
                WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                lp.copyFrom(sortDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
                lp.width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                lp.height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/5;
                sortDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                sortDialog.show();
                //sort controls
                SharedPreferences sortPref = getSharedPreferences("SORT", 0);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sortPref.edit();

                Button exitSort, sortAZ, sortZA, sortCheap, sortExpensive;
                exitSort = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitSort);
                sortAZ = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortAZ);
                sortZA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortZA);
                sortCheap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortCheap);
                sortExpensive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortExpensive);

                exitSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        sortDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                sortAZ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ed.putString("sort", "AZ");
                        ed.commit();
                    }
                });
                sortZA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ed.putString("sort", "ZA");
                        ed.commit();
                    }
                });
                sortCheap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ed.putString("sort", "cheap");
                        ed.commit();
                    }
                });
                sortExpensive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        ed.putString("sort", "expensive");
                        ed.commit();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post the code of your Dialog.

Comment: I hope you're looking for the buttons with `dialog.findViewById()` or directly on the view that you inflate to set as the content view. Also, please don't prefix your questions titles with Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Comment: put your code so that we can help u

Comment: ignore the code where I get data from preferences, I commented that and is not the problem.

Comment: You need to use the dialog object to initialize viewss

    `exitSort = (Button) sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitSort)`. same for others as @Luksprog suggested

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu posted it as ans answer. you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the dialog object to initialize views. As suggested by Luksprog.

You inflate a custom view and set the same to the dialog. You have  buttons  in the layout you inflate. So use the dialog object to initialize your buttons.

```
exitSort = (Button) sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitSort);
sortAZ = (Button)  sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.sortAZ);
sortZA = (Button)  sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.sortZA);
sortCheap = (Button)  sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.sortCheap);
sortExpensive = (Button)  sortDialog.findViewById(R.id.sortExpensive);
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem at line: `sortDialog.dismiss();`

the `"`sortDialog`"` is a `DialogBuilder` object, it's not a `Dialog` `object`.

So you need a variable to handle the dialog when call `show()` function. 
ex:

```
final Dialog dg = sortDialog.show();

and close dialog by "dg":

dg.dismiss();
```